Obj loader collect group vertices
I have nice working obj script but with small bug.
I made group detect rule by adding in blender name with "COLLIDER" and it is a simply non rotated cube.
I also have group detect part.
But i saw in console log that some of (looks like random choose) group always have
all vertices of object.
See printscreen with console logs:

My Obj loader:
'use strict';
import {world} from './matrix-world';

export class constructMesh {

    constructor(objectData, inputArg) {
        this.inputArg = inputArg;
        this.objectData = objectData;
        this.create(objectData, inputArg);
        this.setScale = (s) => {
            this.inputArg.scale = s;
            initMeshBuffers(world.GL.gl, this.create(this.objectData, this.inputArg));
        };
    }

    create = (objectData, inputArg, callback) => {
        if(typeof callback === 'undefined') callback = function() {};
        let initOrientation = [0, 1, 2];
        var verts = [],
            vertNormals = [],
            textures = [],
            unpacked = {};
        // unpacking stuff
        unpacked.verts = [];
        unpacked.norms = [];
        unpacked.textures = [];
        unpacked.hashindices = {};
        unpacked.indices = [];
        unpacked.index = 0;
        // array of lines separated by the newline
        var lines = objectData.split('\n');

        // test group catch data bpund or center
        var objGroups = [];
        // update swap orientation
        if(inputArg.swap[0] !== null) {
            swap(inputArg.swap[0], inputArg.swap[1], initOrientation);
        }

        var VERTEX_RE = /^v\s/;
        var NORMAL_RE = /^vn\s/;
        var TEXTURE_RE = /^vt\s/;
        var FACE_RE = /^f\s/;
        var WHITESPACE_RE = /\s+/;

        for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++) {
            var line = lines[i].trim();
            var elements = line.split(WHITESPACE_RE);
            elements.shift();

            if(VERTEX_RE.test(line)) {
                // if this is a vertex
                verts.push.apply(verts, elements);

                if(objGroups.length > 0) {
                    objGroups[objGroups.length - 1].groupVert.push(elements)
                }

            } else if(NORMAL_RE.test(line)) {
                // if this is a vertex normal
                vertNormals.push.apply(vertNormals, elements);
            } else if(TEXTURE_RE.test(line)) {
                // if this is a texture
                textures.push.apply(textures, elements);
            } else if(FACE_RE.test(line)) {
                // if this is a face
                /*
                    split this face into an array of vertex groups
                    for example:
                        f 16/92/11 14/101/22 1/69/1
                    becomes:
                        ['16/92/11', '14/101/22', '1/69/1'];
                    */
                var quad = false;
                for(var j = 0, eleLen = elements.length;j < eleLen;j++) {
                    // Triangulating quads
                    // quad: 'f v0/t0/vn0 v1/t1/vn1 v2/t2/vn2 v3/t3/vn3/'
                    // corresponding triangles:
                    //      'f v0/t0/vn0 v1/t1/vn1 v2/t2/vn2'
                    //      'f v2/t2/vn2 v3/t3/vn3 v0/t0/vn0'
                    if(j === 3 && !quad) {
                        // add v2/t2/vn2 in again before continuing to 3
                        j = 2;
                        quad = true;
                    }
                    if(elements[j] in unpacked.hashindices) {
                        unpacked.indices.push(unpacked.hashindices[elements[j]]);
                    } else {
                        var vertex = elements[j].split('/');

                        if(typeof inputArg.scale == "number") {
                            unpacked.verts.push(+verts[(vertex[0] - 1) * 3 + initOrientation[0]] * inputArg.scale);
                            unpacked.verts.push(+verts[(vertex[0] - 1) * 3 + initOrientation[1]] * inputArg.scale);
                            unpacked.verts.push(+verts[(vertex[0] - 1) * 3 + initOrientation[2]] * inputArg.scale);
                        } else {
                            unpacked.verts.push(+verts[(vertex[0] - 1) * 3 + initOrientation[0]] * inputArg.scale.x);
                            unpacked.verts.push(+verts[(vertex[0] - 1) * 3 + initOrientation[1]] * inputArg.scale.y);
                            unpacked.verts.push(+verts[(vertex[0] - 1) * 3 + initOrientation[2]] * inputArg.scale.z);
                        }

                        // vertex textures
                        if(textures.length) {
                            unpacked.textures.push(+textures[(vertex[1] - 1) * 2 + 0]);
                            unpacked.textures.push(+textures[(vertex[1] - 1) * 2 + 1]);
                        }
                        // vertex normals
                        unpacked.norms.push(+vertNormals[(vertex[2] - 1) * 3 + 0]);
                        unpacked.norms.push(+vertNormals[(vertex[2] - 1) * 3 + 1]);
                        unpacked.norms.push(+vertNormals[(vertex[2] - 1) * 3 + 2]);
                        // add the newly created vertex to the list of indices
                        unpacked.hashindices[elements[j]] = unpacked.index;
                        unpacked.indices.push(unpacked.index);
                        // increment the counter
                        unpacked.index += 1;
                    }
                    if(j === 3 && quad) {
                        // add v0/t0/vn0 onto the second triangle
                        unpacked.indices.push(unpacked.hashindices[elements[0]]);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if(line.indexOf('# ') != -1) {
                    // console.log('obj loader comment:', line)
                } else if(line.indexOf('mtllib') != -1) {
                    // console.log('obj loader MTL file:', line)
                } else if(line.indexOf('g ') != -1) {
                    // console.log('obj loader group :', line)
                    var nameOFGroup = line.split(' ')[1]
                    if(nameOFGroup.indexOf('COLLIDER') != -1) {
                        console.log('obj loader group [SPECIAL CASE COLLIDER]:', nameOFGroup)
                        objGroups.push({
                            groupName: nameOFGroup,
                            groupVert: []
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        this.vertices = unpacked.verts;
        this.vertexNormals = unpacked.norms;
        this.textures = unpacked.textures;
        this.indices = unpacked.indices;

        if(objGroups.length > 0) {
            this.groups = objGroups;
        } else {
            this.groups = null;
        }
        callback();
        return this;
    };

}

var Ajax = function() {
    // this is just a helper class to ease ajax calls
    var _this = this;
    this.xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    this.get = function(url, callback) {
        _this.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(_this.xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
                callback(_this.xmlhttp.responseText, _this.xmlhttp.status);
            }
        };
        _this.xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
        _this.xmlhttp.send();
    };
};

export var downloadMeshes = function(nameAndURLs, completionCallback, inputArg) {
    var semaphore = Object.keys(nameAndURLs).length;
    var error = false;
    if(typeof inputArg === 'undefined') {
        var inputArg = {
            scale: 1,
            swap: [null]
        };
    }
    if(typeof inputArg.scale === 'undefined') inputArg.scale = 1;
    if(typeof inputArg.swap === 'undefined') inputArg.swap = [null];
    var meshes = {};
    for(var mesh_name in nameAndURLs) {
        if(nameAndURLs.hasOwnProperty(mesh_name)) {
            new Ajax().get(
                nameAndURLs[mesh_name],
                (function(name) {
                    return function(data, status) {
                        if(status === 200) {
                            meshes[name] = new constructMesh(data, inputArg);
                        } else {
                            error = true;
                            console.error('An error has occurred and the mesh "' + name + '" could not be downloaded.');
                        }
                        // the request has finished, decrement the counter
                        semaphore--;
                        if(semaphore === 0) {
                            if(error) {
                                // if an error has occurred, the user is notified here and the
                                // callback is not called
                                console.error('An error has occurred and one or meshes has not been ' + 'downloaded. The execution of the script has terminated.');
                                throw '';
                            }
                            // there haven't been any errors in retrieving the meshes
                            // call the callback
                            completionCallback(meshes);
                        }
                    };
                })(mesh_name)
            );
        }
    }
};

var _buildBuffer = function(gl, type, data, itemSize) {
    var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    var arrayView = type === gl.ARRAY_BUFFER ? Float32Array : Uint16Array;
    gl.bindBuffer(type, buffer);
    gl.bufferData(type, new arrayView(data), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    buffer.itemSize = itemSize;
    buffer.numItems = data.length / itemSize;
    return buffer;
};

export var initMeshBuffers = function(gl, mesh) {
    mesh.normalBuffer = _buildBuffer(gl, gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vertexNormals, 3);
    mesh.textureBuffer = _buildBuffer(gl, gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.textures, 2);
    mesh.vertexBuffer = _buildBuffer(gl, gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vertices, 3);
    mesh.indexBuffer = _buildBuffer(gl, gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.indices, 1);
};

export var deleteMeshBuffers = function(gl, mesh) {
    gl.deleteBuffer(mesh.normalBuffer);
    gl.deleteBuffer(mesh.textureBuffer);
    gl.deleteBuffer(mesh.vertexBuffer);
    gl.deleteBuffer(mesh.indexBuffer);
};

/**
 * @description
 * Construct sequence list argument for downloadMeshes.
 * This is adaptation for blender obj animation export.
 * For example:
 *    matrixEngine.objLoader.downloadMeshes(
            matrixEngine.objLoader.makeObjSeqArg(
                {
                    id: objName,
                    joinMultiPahts: [
                        {
                            path: "res/bvh-skeletal-base/swat-guy/seq-walk/low/swat",
                            id: objName,
                            from: 1, to: 34
                        },
                        {
                            path: "res/bvh-skeletal-base/swat-guy/seq-walk-pistol/low/swat-walk-pistol",
                            id: objName,
                            from: 35, to: 54
                        }
                    ]
                }),
            onLoadObj
        );
 */
export const makeObjSeqArg = (arg) => {
    // Adaptation for blender (animation) obj exporter.
    var local = {};
    function localCalc(arg, noInitial = false) {
        var zeros = '00000';
        var l = {};
        var helper = arg.from;
        for(let j = arg.from, z = 1;j <= arg.to;j++) {
            if(z > 9 && z < 99) {
                zeros = '0000';
            } else if(z > 99 && z < 999) {
                zeros = '000';
            } // no need more then 999
            if(helper == arg.from && noInitial === false) {
                l[arg.id] = arg.path + '_' + zeros + z + '.obj';
            } else {
                l[arg.id + (helper - 1)] = arg.path + '_' + zeros + z + '.obj';
            }
            helper++;
            z++;
        }
        return l;
    }

    if(typeof arg.path === 'string') {
        local = localCalc(arg);
    } else if(typeof arg.path === 'undefined') {
        if(typeof arg.joinMultiPahts !== 'undefined') {
            console.log("ITS joinMultiPahts!");
            var localFinal = {};
            arg.joinMultiPahts.forEach((arg, index) => {
                if(index === 0) {
                    localFinal = Object.assign(local, localCalc(arg));
                } else {
                    localFinal = Object.assign(local, localCalc(arg, true));
                }
            });
            console.log("joinMultiPahts LOCAL => ", localFinal);
            return localFinal;
        }
    }
    return local;
}


Any suggestion ?
